# US B1/B2 renewal without interview: do eligibility rules differ in different embassies?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

My B1/B2 visa recently expired and I want to renew it. I know that there is an option to renew it without going for another interview, it should be sufficient to send a passport and supporting documents by post.

I checked webpages of several US embassies in different countries and it seems many of them have completely different requirements. E.g., some require that:

- The old visa was issued in the same embassy
- You are a citizen/resident of the country where the embassy is located
- The old visa was a 10-year-long visa (i.e. not 1-year), etc.
- Some embassies (e.g. in Georgia) do not have any information 
  regarding that renewal option at all.

So I want to check if it is indeed the case, i.e. do embassies themselves define the eligibility conditions, or are there some baseline conditions that work everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are specific requirements for whether a US visa applicant receives an interview. These are specified in US law and in the Foreign Affairs Manual which is the official guidance for US State Department employees on how to do their jobs.

[9 FAM 403.5](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040305.html) covers visa interviews and you may wish to read it in its entirety. It specifies the conditions under which an interview can be waived. It also specifies the conditions under which an interview *cannot* be waived, but that section is not unclassified and therefore not publicly available. It is certainly possible, because at least some of these conditions are based on local or regional threat intelligence, that conditions may vary from one consulate to another.